# Seeing some (green'ish, purple'ish) lines on monitor

Tags: display

I see some (green'ish, purple'ish) lines on my monitor. Does anyone have any idea what this is? Does this look repairable?

[image: lines on screen]

PS: I am not sure if this is the best place to ask this queston. Let me know if there are any other stackoverflow sites which are more suited to hardware questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a friend with lines that look exactly like this, except orange on his laptop. I believe it was a result of it being stepped on or dropped. In this case, the only way to fix it would be to get the screen replaced.

Comment: It has been subject to some rough handling which could be the reason. I will accept your answer maybe in a day.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a really old monitor? I've seen this happen on a really old, second hand LCD display - its due to the layers of the LCD seperating - looks almost like there's a fern-like dendrite formation between layers. Its not fixable in my experience.

Since its actual physical damage, it probably would be visible when the monior is off, if you shine a light at the screen

Comment: It's not that old.

Comment: although the layers could separate if it was abused